# I want to add the data from other sheets without copying the header again and again

Tags: vba

I want to add the data from other sheets without copying the header again and again.

This code copy data from different sheets and collate in one sheet. But it includes header every time i merge the data under previous data. I want to add the data from other sheets without copying the header.

```
sub collate_data()
    thisworkbook.sheets.add after:=sheets("Orders")
    Activesheet.name = "finalsheet"
    c = sheets("Control2nd").range("A100").End(Xlup).row

    for i = 1 to c
        a = sheets("Finalsheet").range("A10000").End(xlup).Row
        b = sheets("Control2nd").range("A" & i).value
        Thisworkbook.sheets(b).Range("A1:W90").Copy
        Thisworkbook.sheets("FinalSheet").Range("A" & a).select
        activesheet.Paste
    Next
End Sub
```

Expected result should header should be pasted only once and other sheets data should be pasted without header.

Comment: I think `If i=1 then` : `Thisworkbook.sheets(b).Range("A1:W90").Copy` :  `Else` `Thisworkbook.sheets(b).Range("A2:W90").Copy` : `End if` would do If Row 1 is the header

Comment: Ok , this might work , this will copy the 1st sheet with the header and rest without the header . Thank you Ahmed AU.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see exactly what you want, but I gave it a try. This may work:

```
Sub collate_data()
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Variant

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Sheets("Orders")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "finalsheet"
    c = Sheets("Control2nd").Range("A100").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To c
        a = Sheets("Finalsheet").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
        b = Sheets("Control2nd").Range("A" & i).Value
        If i = 1 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(b).Range("A1:W90").Copy
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(b).Range("A2:W90").Copy
        End If
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalSheet").Range("A" & a).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If it worked, please accept the answer and upvote. Thx.